# MongoDB Models not connecting through Schema embedded objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a blog app. Here one user has a one-to-many relationship with posts.After creating the basic CRUD I wanted to make a profile page featuring all the posts of a single User. I am following all the steps but still when I fetch all users I get empty array of Post.

And also I am trying to get user name in each post instead of only ID. I am using Populate but still getting only user id back.

```js
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const Posts = await Post.find()
   .sort({
    date: -1
   })
   .populate('users');
  res.json(Posts);
 } catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
  res.status(500).send('Server Error');
 }
});
```

Here's my user schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 posts: [
  {
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'Post'
  }
 ],
 email: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true
 },
 password: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 date: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
 }
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Here's Post Schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 user: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User'
 },
 title: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 content: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 date: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
 }
});

const Post = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am following all the steps but still when I fetch all users I get empty array of Post

When you add a new *post* you must also update the `posts` field of the `userSchema`:

```
const newPost = await Post.insert(/* post */);
await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: newPost.user }, { $push: { posts: newPost._id }, { new: true });
```

> And also I am trying to get user name in each post instead of only ID. I am using Populate but still getting only user id back

Try `.populate('user');` without `s`

Comment: Thanks a lot I tried the first one and it worked. But the problem I already have 20+ posts and some users which aren't configured in this way. What's the solution for this issue.

Comment: The second one removing s gave an error. Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Comment: You could `find` all posts and use a loop to update users' posts, for the second one try to capitalize `post`  and `user` in `mongoose.model(name, schema)` like this: `mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);`